# JSON to pandas dataframe with nested lists

Tags: python, json, pandas

I run the following code and it outputs the json below.

```
import requests
url="xxxx"
r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
j=r.json()

recs = j['collection']
```

**Json**

```
{'stationCode': 'NB001',
       'summaries': [{'period': {'year': 2017}, 'rainfall': 449},
        {'period': {'year': 2018}, 'rainfall': 352.4},
        {'period': {'year': 2019}, 'rainfall': 253.2},
        {'period': {'year': 2020}, 'rainfall': 283},
        {'period': {'year': 2021}, 'rainfall': 104.2}]},{'stationCode': 'NA003','summaries': [{'period': {'year': 2019}, 'rainfall': 58.2},{'period': {'year': 2020}, 'rainfall': 628.2},{'period': {'year': 2021}, 'rainfall': 120}]}
```

I need this output as follows into a table

[image]

Tried the following and I still could extract table with multiple added lines but just wondered if there was a faster way

```
df = json_normalize(recs)
df
```

Comment: the data shared is a tuple of dicts. if you could share the proper json form, that would be better

Comment: I see what you mean. Unless I give you the url to scrape. Equating it to a variable makes it a tuple?

Comment: the comma actually makes it a tuple. looks like you copied a small part of it (which is fine though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for each entry in the tuple (the data you shared is a tuple of dicts):

```
from pandas import json_normalize
In [333]: pd.concat([json_normalize(entry, 'summaries', 'stationCode') 
                     for entry in recs])
Out[333]: 
   rainfall  period.year stationCode
0     449.0         2017       NB001
1     352.4         2018       NB001
2     253.2         2019       NB001
3     283.0         2020       NB001
4     104.2         2021       NB001
0      58.2         2019       NA003
1     628.2         2020       NA003
2     120.0         2021       NA003
```

Alternative solution: I like [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/), as it can be quite helpful for some gnarly nested options in json. The short story for using `jmespath` (it is sort of a language of its own with loads of functions) is if you are accessing a key, then the dot comes in to play, if it is a list, then the `[]` symbol is used:

```
import jmespath
expression = jmespath.compile("""{stationcode:stationCode, 
                                  year: summaries[].period.year, 
                                  rainfall: summaries[].rainfall}""")

outcome = [pd.DataFrame(expression.search(entry)) for entry in recs]
pd.concat(outcome)

  stationcode  year  rainfall
0       NB001  2017     449.0
1       NB001  2018     352.4
2       NB001  2019     253.2
3       NB001  2020     283.0
4       NB001  2021     104.2
0       NA003  2019      58.2
1       NA003  2020     628.2
2       NA003  2021     120.0
```

Just an arsenal in your tool, if [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) does not quite cut it. For raw speed, the built-in dict is king.

Comment: Good one @sammywemmy

Comment: Nice answer. But this is slower than the solution when parsing `recs`.

Comment: didnt bother to check speed; besides json_normalize is more of a convenience feature. if you dont mind adding the speed to your solution; would be great and a good learning point

Comment: @sammywemmy, happy to post a question. Just dont want to put it out there because answers can be quite low quality. If I have the following. How do I get each entity as a column? You seemed to have fair bit of arsenals

Comment: `[{"id": "1617844808_49195291","trip_update": {"trip": {"trip_id": "49195291","direction_id": 0,"route_id": "100001","start_date": "20210407","schedule_relationship": "SCHEDULED"},"stop_time_update": [{"stop_sequence": 101,"stop_id": "2390","arrival": {"delay": -492,"time": 1617844044 },"departure": {"delay": -492,"time": 1617844044},"schedule_relationship": "SCHEDULED"},{"stop_sequence": 110,"stop_id": "2400","arrival": {"delay": -492, "time": 1617844093},"departure": {"delay": -492,"time": 1617844093},"schedule_relationship": "SCHEDULED"}]}}]`

Comment: @wwnde I cannot find entity in the list provided. Could you make it a bit clearer? or share code of expected output

Comment: Basically I have sent you x. from the following {
 '`"header": {
    "gtfs_realtime_version": "2.0",
    "incrementality": 0,
    "timestamp": 1617942493
  },
  "entity": [x

  ]
}`

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: @wwnde, still lost bro. makes sense if i see the expected output

Comment: Not complete, but literally unnesst everything. `pd.DataFrame({'id':['1617844808_49195291'],'trip_id':['49195291'],'route_id':['100001'],'start_date':['20210407'],'stop_sequence':[101],'stop_id':['2390'],'arrival-delay':['-492'],'arrival-time':['1617844044']})
`

Comment: I cant share the actual data so I had to draw this for sample `https://s3.amazonaws.com/kcm-alerts-realtime-prod/tripupdates_pb.json`

Comment: alright give me some minutes to work with it, the output makes everything so clear!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230923/discussion-between-wwnde-and-sammywemmy).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
In [956]: def f2():
     ...:     df = pd.DataFrame(recs)
     ...:     df = df.explode('summaries')
     ...:     df['year'] = df.summaries.str.get('period').str.get('year')
     ...:     df['rainfall'] = df.summaries.str.get('rainfall')
     ...:     df.drop('summaries', 1, inplace=True)
     ...: 

In [908]: df
Out[908]: 
  stationCode  year  rainfall
0       NB001  2017     449.0
0       NB001  2018     352.4
0       NB001  2019     253.2
0       NB001  2020     283.0
0       NB001  2021     104.2
1       NA003  2019      58.2
1       NA003  2020     628.2
1       NA003  2021     120.0
```

**OR:**

Parse the `recs` dict separately, which should be more efficient:

```
In [952]: def f1():
     ...:     s = []
     ...:     y = []
     ...:     r = []
     ...:     for k,v in recs[0].items():
     ...:         if k == 'stationCode':
     ...:             s.append(v)
     ...:     else:
     ...:         for i in v:
     ...:             y.append(i['period']['year'])
     ...:             r.append(i['rainfall'])
     ...:     s = s * len(y)
     ...:     df = pd.DataFrame({'stationCode': s, 'year': y, 'rainfall':r})
```

**Timings for both:**

```
In [955]: %timeit f1()
385 µs ± 20.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [969]: %timeit f2()
3.48 ms ± 224 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: +1, However, thats what I meant. Could get it done with a couple of additional lines. Any straight up method?

Comment: No straight up method as such. One other way could be parsing `recs` to get a straight-forward `dict` instead of parsing columns in `df`.

Comment: @wwnde Please check my updated answer. Have put timings as well.

Comment: Thanks @Mayank Porwal, Wemmy's answer is all encampassing. unpacks nested json lists as well. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sure @wwnde. No problem